# EntityManager persist performing much better on Ubuntu Desktop than other systems

Tags: java

I'm trying to import an excel file into mySQL. There're 20k-30k records to be imported. I'm using Hibernate and running on JBOSS 7.1.1, and the EntityManager is annotated with @PersistenceContext.

The problem is that while the import takes around 90 seconds on a VM of Ubuntu Desktop, the same code times out after 5 minutes (with less than half records processed, and the transaction rolls back) on other systems. I've tried another instance of Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server and Windows 7.

I've clearly changed something, but from what I can tell the standalone.XML file is the same, and none of the JAVA_OPTS have been changed. I've no idea what to look for that would cause the em.persist() method to be so different.

I know I'm being a bit vague, but I really don't know what I might have changed in the system

Comment: so u are looking for a way to decrease the 5 minutes to the 90 seconds or for a way to higher the timeout time?

Comment: There could be many points of difference between execution environments like: are the used Hibernate versions the same? Are the MySQL versions the same?
Anyway, I suggest you not to use Hibernate for such massive data. You could do some bulk insert using MySQL's `LOAD DATA` and gain so much time on any platform. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: Felix, I was hoping to decrease the time down to 90 seconds, similar to the Ubuntu performance.

blint, both versions are the same. I previously had similar code running on a Tomcat server (I was using entitymanagerfactory though, not the @PersistenceContext), and the performance was same on Windows and Ubuntu.
Also, doesn't the mySQL LOAD DATA only work with CSV files? I'm using a HTML input form to import an xls file - that wouldn't work, would it?

Comment: zodac, you could pre-process your data: instead of writing in the DB (calling hibernate `save`s for example), you could write a line in some CSV file. After writing the whole file, you would do your bulk insert, and the whole process should run even much faster than 90s!

Comment: Any news on your issue? I could write a detailed answer if you're interested in this solution

Comment: I'm currently trying to load the data into the table from a csv file. At the moment I'm having two problems:
1) Large long values (15 digits) are coming up in the form 1.15044E+18. Just trying to fix that in the Java code.
2) Even when manually changed, using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is just entering all 0/NULL values into the table, with no warnings.